# Car runs "fine" only without camshaft position sensor

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, chevy-spark

I bought a used Chevrolet Spark (aka matiz) with a 3 cylinder engine (F8CV engine) a month ago and I noticed some issues:

1. difficulty starting the engine
2. intermittent stalling when in neutral
3. very poor mileage

So I bought a code scanner and it gave me P0342 "Camshaft Position Sensor Circuit Low Input". So I replaced the sensor and all three issues completely vanished. The code never showed up again.

But now, I have another issue that I didn't have before. The engine loses power and misfires when acceleration (only under load, idles and revs great in neutral). Especially in the lower rev range. No codes are showing up in the scanner. And this issue surfaced immediately after replacing the camshaft position sensor and no other maintenance was done to the vehicle.

**I tried unplugging the camshaft position sensor and the hesitation went away. It's only when I plug the CPS sensor that the problem surfaces.**

Does anyone have an idea how replacing a defective sensor with a fully working one could cause an issue like this?

Here's a [service manual for a similar engine](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1212501/Daewoo-Matiz.html) if it helps

Edit: this car does not have an EGR. And does not have any sensor plugged to the exhaust.

Comment: You need to talk to this guy, he has exactly the same issue - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/85701/engine-misfires-and-loses-power-after-replacing-faulty-camshaft-position-sensor/85702#comment147353_85702

Comment: Does the manual detail any coding procedure or re-learning procedure?